# "variable, variable =" syntax in python?

Tags: python

I'm just getting started in python, and either haven't read about this, or missed it, and I don't know what to search for to find my answer.

Playing around with the IMAP module I came across this line of code.

```
result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")
```

What is happening with the two variables here? Is this a syntax that is used when methods return a certain way, or does it always work? Could someone either explain what's going on here, or point me to some documentation?

Comment: on a side note `a,b=b,a` is a slick pythonic way of swapping values :) the first time I saw that I was floored

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- I never find a real need to swap values in my code, but everytime I see that it makes me smile.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a form of sequence unpacking.  If the RHS is an iterable of length 2 (since you have 2 objects on the LHS), you can use it.  e.g.:

```
a,b = (1, 2)  #The RHS here is a tuple, but it could be a list, generator, etc.
print a #1
print b #2
```

Python3 extends this in an interesting way to allow the RHS to have more values than the LHS:

```
a,b,*rest = range(30) 
print(a) #0
print(b) #1
print(rest == list(range(2,30))) #True
```

Comment: Another name for this is _destructuring_.

Comment: @RolandTepp -- Interesting.  I haven't seen that term used before.  I'll have to look for it next time.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign multiple variables in Python in one line: -

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
```

Assigns three values 1, 2, 3 to a, b, c respectively.

Similarly you can assign values from a list to variables.

```
>>> li = [1, 2, 3]    
>>> a, b, c = li
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
```

This unpacks your list into 3 variables

Answer (score 0):

This is multiple assignment: the variables result and data simultaneously get the new values returned from mail.search(none, ALL).

The expressions on the right-hand side are all evaluated first before any of the assignments take place. The right-hand side expressions are evaluated from the left to the right.

the multiple assignment documentation is here

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html